# Java Bloomberg API - how to generate a Request without a Service

Tags: java, bloomberg

I am using the Bloomberg API to grab data.  Currently, I have 3 processes which get data in the typical way as per the developers guide.  Something like:

```
Service refDataService = session.getService("//blp/refdata");
Request request = refDataService.createRequest("ReferenceDataRequest");
request.append("securities", "IBM US Equity");
request.append("fields", "PX_LAST");
cid = session.sendRequest(request, null);
```

That works.  Now I would like to expand the logic to be something more like an update queue.  I would like each process to send their Request to an update queue process, which would in turn be responsible for creating the session and service, and then sending the requests.  However, I don't see of any way to create the request without the Service.  Also, since the request types (referenceData, historical data, intraday ticks) are so varied and have such different properties, it is not trivial to create a container object which my update queue could read.

Any ideas on how to accomplish this?  My ultimate goal is to have a process (I'm calling update queue) which takes in a list of requests, removes any duplicates, and goes out to Bloomberg for the data in 30 second intervals.

Thank you!

Comment: If that is of any interest, I have developed a [Java wrapper](https://github.com/assylias/jbloomberg) around the Bloomberg API which could make this easier (i.e. all types of request are created via builders which all implement the same interface and all results are put in a RequestResult object). You can see a sample code at the bottom of [the javadoc page](http://assylias.github.com/jBloomberg/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: Great, I should be able to use this, thank you!  Any chance you've been working on a IntraDayTickBuilder class?

Comment: Not yet - I will probably include one in the next few days.

Comment: Great!  Thank you, I will keep looking out for it.  By the way, what is the Stack Overflow etiquette - this is definitely what I needed but I can't accept a comment as the answer

Comment: I have added an answer with more details. I have completely revamped the API to include tick data and it looks much better now. Thanks for the little push!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated the [jBloomberg](https://github.com/assylias/jBloomberg) library to include tick data. You can submit different types of query to a [BloombergSession](http://assylias.github.com/jBloomberg/apidocs/assylias/jbloomberg/BloombergSession.html) which acts as a queue. So if you want to submit different types of request you can write something like:

```
RequestBuilder<IntradayTickData> tickRequest =
    new IntradayTickRequestBuilder("SPX Index",
        DateTime.now().minusHours(2),
        DateTime.now());

RequestBuilder<IntradayBarData> barRequest =
    new IntradayBarRequestBuilder("SPX Index",
        DateTime.now().minusHours(2),
        DateTime.now())
        .period(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES);

RequestBuilder<ReferenceData> refRequest =
    new ReferenceRequestBuilder("SPX Index", "NAME");

Future<IntradayTickData> ticks = session.submit(tickRequest);
Future<IntradayBarData> bars = session.submit(barRequest);
Future<ReferenceData> name = session.submit(refRequest);
```

More examples available in [the javadoc](http://assylias.github.io/jBloomberg/apidocs/index.html).

If you need to fetch the same information regularly, you can reuse a builder and use it in combination with a [ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) for example.

Note: the library is still in beta state so don't use it blindly in an black box that trades automatically!

Comment: This is great, thank you!  By the way, I am using blpapi-3.4.8-1.jar and I have no issue using the `includeNonPlottableEvents` flag (in fact I have to in order to see the trades I'm interested in).  Your variable is called `includeNonPlottable` so it might just be a typo.  In the developer's guide it breaks it down on two lines so maybe that is why.  Thanks again, this is exactly what I needed!

Comment: @Marianna Well spotted! I had missed the second line indeed. I've just pushed an update. Thanks!

Comment: @assylias is there any place we can find more examples for the  jBloomberg 
 library

Comment: Bottom of [this page](http://assylias.github.io/jBloomberg/apidocs/index.html)